# What does "lending themselves to being long" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Can somebody explain the phrase in bold for me, please?

> "That tells me that both markets remain skeptical about the continuity of this potential growth as we go forward," he said, adding that **these issues are lending themselves to being long** the dollar right now would be "very, very dangerous" due to such uncertainty.

Source: [Is the dollar’s run done? Why some traders say yes](http://www.cnbc.com/2017/02/19/is-the-dollars-run-done-why-some-traders-say-yes.html) on CNBC

Comment: This sentence is a mess; it cannot be parsed as it stands. I suspect that either something has dropped out or a rewrite has not been carried through fully. ... But *being long the dollar* is not problematic; it means 'holding a "long" position' in the dollar, buying dollars now in the expectation that the value of the dollar will rise.

Comment: The sentence is gibberish to me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the sentence in question appears to be badly garbled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence is badly mangled, but I think understanding the financial terms might help.

The phrase "[being long](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_%28finance%29)" means an investor has invested their money in a particular [security](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/security.asp) in a way that if the value goes up they will make a profit. It usually means the investor has a positive outlook on the financial instrument (stock, options, exchange traded fund, etc.). Usually this means that the investor has purchased or borrowed a large number of shares and is holding on to them until the price goes up.

The opposite of "being long" is "[shorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_(finance))" or "going short" where the investor has invested their money in a way that would make money if the value of the financial instrument went down. One way to do that is to borrow shares of a security and offer them for sale at a higher price, then buy them back when the price drops to return them to the broker. The profit is the difference between the price the shares were sold at and the price the investor was able to purchase them back at with the fees for borrowing the shares from the broker subtracted. If the price goes up instead of down, the investor loses money.